# ¿Existe un tamaño máximo para una URL?

Tags: http, url

A lo que me refiero es si existe un límite en el número de caracteres que puede contener una URL, y cuál sería el valor de ese límite si es que existe.

Comment: Esta respuesta en S.O podría ayudarte. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según el [RFC2616 - protocolo HTTP1.1, sec3.2.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1)

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the server can handle

**No** hay límite para dicha longitud. Depende exclusivamente de lo que cada cliente y servidor soporte.

No obstante:

> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>         above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>         implementations might not properly support these lengths.

**Se recomienda** que dicha longitud **no exceda** de los 255 *bytes*, para que sea plenamente soportada por clientes o *proxy*s antiguos,

Answer (score 4):

La longitud máxima de la dirección URL es variable, dependiendo del navegador por ejemplo en el famoso Internet Explorer es de 2083 caracteres.

Aqui te dejo los datos:

Internet Explorer: 2,083 carácteres.
Firefox: 65, 536 carácteres.
Safari: 80.000 carácteres.
Opera: 190.000 carácteres.

y por servidor web:

```
Apache: 4,000 carácteres
Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS): 16, 384 carácteres.
Perl HTTP::Daemon: 8.000 caracteres.
```

Un poco de investigación no hace daño amigo.

Comment: Añadir que el límite actual en Chrome es de 2MB. Este tema se discute aquí:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227